# python piecewise linear interpolation

Tags: python, 3d, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to create a piecewise linear interpolation routine and I'm pretty new to all of this so I'm very uncertain of what needs to be done.

I've generate a set of data points in 3D which gives variation in all 3 directions. I want to interpolate between these data points and plot in 3D.

The current data set is much smaller than the final one will be. Linear interpolation is important.

here's the current code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.interpolate as interp


x = np.linspace(-1.3,1.3,10)
y1 = np.linspace(.5,0.,5)
y2 = np.linspace(0.,.5,5)
y = np.hstack((y1,y2))
z1 = np.linspace(.1,0.,5)
z2 = np.linspace(0.,.1,5)
z = np.hstack((z1,z2))

data = np.dstack([x,y,z])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


f = interp.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')
xnew = np.linspace(-1.3,1.3,100)
y1new = np.linspace(.5,0.,50)
y2new = np.linspace(0.,.5,50)
ynew = np.hstack((y1new,y2new))
znew = f(xnew,ynew)

ax.plot(x,y,znew, 'b-')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,'ro')
plt.show()
```

As I said, dataset is just to add variation. The real set will be much bigger but have less variation. I don't really understand the interpolation tool and the scipy documentation isn't very clear

would appreciate suggestions

Comment: Did you see the example here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: Plotting examples can be found here https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply. Yes I've seen it thanks but it plots a 2D representation. I want a 3D representation and what I get is something completely weird and the lines don't go through the data points. So either I'm using the incorrect interpolation function or I'm messing up on the 3D plotting. The example isn't helpful for my situation unfortunately.

Comment: Try to adjust this function to interp2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536822/7919597