# Spline in 3D can not be differentiated due to an AttributeError

Tags: python, scipy, spline, derivative

I am trying to fit a smoothing B-spline to some data and I found this very helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962175/spline-interpolation-coefficients-of-a-line-curve-in-3d-space) on here. However, I not only need the spline, but also its derivatives, so I tried to add the following code to the example:

```
tck_der = interpolate.splder(tck, n=1)
x_der, y_der, z_der = interpolate.splev(u_fine, tck_der)
```

For some reason this does not seem to work due to some data type issues. I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interpolate_point_trace.py", line 31, in spline_example
    tck_der = interpolate.splder(tck, n=1)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 657, in splder
     return _impl.splder(tck, n)
   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py", line 1206, in splder
     sh = (slice(None),) + ((None,)*len(c.shape[1:]))
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The reason for this seems to be that the second argument of the `tck` tuple contains a list of `numpy` arrays. I thought turning the input data to be a `numpy` array as well would help, but it does not change the data types of `tck`.

Does this behavior reflect an error in `scipy`, or is the input malformed? 
I tried manually turning the list into an array:

```
tck[1] = np.array(tck[1])
```

but this (which didn't surprise me) also gave an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,8) (7,1)
```

Any ideas of what the problem could be? I have used `scipy` before and on 1D splines the `splder` function works just fine, so I assume it has something to do with the spline being a line in 3D.

------- edit --------

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

total_rad = 10
z_factor = 3
noise = 0.1

num_true_pts = 200
s_true = np.linspace(0, total_rad, num_true_pts)
x_true = np.cos(s_true)
y_true = np.sin(s_true)
z_true = s_true / z_factor

num_sample_pts = 80
s_sample = np.linspace(0, total_rad, num_sample_pts)
x_sample = np.cos(s_sample) + noise * np.random.randn(num_sample_pts)
y_sample = np.sin(s_sample) + noise * np.random.randn(num_sample_pts)
z_sample = s_sample / z_factor + noise * np.random.randn(num_sample_pts)

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x_sample, y_sample, z_sample], s=2)
x_knots, y_knots, z_knots = interpolate.splev(tck[0], tck)
u_fine = np.linspace(0, 1, num_true_pts)
x_fine, y_fine, z_fine = interpolate.splev(u_fine, tck)

# this is the part of the code I inserted: the line under this causes the crash
tck_der = interpolate.splder(tck, n=1)
x_der, y_der, z_der = interpolate.splev(u_fine, tck_der)

# end of the inserted code

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax3d = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3d.plot(x_true, y_true, z_true, 'b')
ax3d.plot(x_sample, y_sample, z_sample, 'r*')
ax3d.plot(x_knots, y_knots, z_knots, 'go')
ax3d.plot(x_fine, y_fine, z_fine, 'g')
fig2.show()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a minimum working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled into the same problem...

I circumvented the error by using `interpolate.splder(tck, n=1)` and instead used `interpolate.splev(spline_ev, tck, der=1)` which returns the derivatives at the points `spline_ev` (see [Scipy Doku](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html#scipy.interpolate.splev)).

If you need the spline I think you can then use `interpolate.splprep()` again.

In total something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.rand(10,2) * 10

(tck, u), fp, ier, msg = interpolate.splprep(points.T, s=0, k=3, full_output=True)

spline_ev = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100, endpoint=True)

spline_points = interpolate.splev(spline_ev, tck)

# Calculate derivative
spline_der_points = interpolate.splev(spline_ev, tck, der=1)
spline_der = interpolate.splprep(spline_der_points.T, s=0, k=3, full_output=True)


# Plot the data and derivative
fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], '.-', label="points")
plt.plot(spline_points[0], spline_points[1], '.-', label="tck")
plt.plot(spline_der_points[0], spline_der_points[1], '.-', label="tck_der")

#   Show tangent
plt.arrow(spline_points[0][23]-spline_der_points[0][23], spline_points[1][23]-spline_der_points[1][23], 2.0*spline_der_points[0][23], 2.0*spline_der_points[1][23])

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

### EDIT:

I also opened an Issue on [Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10389) and according to **ev-br** the usage of `interpolate.splprep` is depreciated and one should use `make_interp_spline` / `BSpline` instead.

Comment: thanks so much for sharing your solution! I will try it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, `splprep` output is incompatible with `splder`, but is compatible with `splev`. And the latter can evaluate the derivatives.

However, for *interpolation*, there is an alternative approach, which avoids `splprep` altogether. I'm basically copying a reply on the SciPy issue tracker (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10389):

Here's an example of replicating the `splprep` outputs. First let's make sense out of the `splprep` output:

```
# start with the OP example
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

points = np.random.rand(10,2) * 10

(tck, u), fp, ier, msg = interpolate.splprep(points.T, s=0, k=3, full_output=True)

# check the meaning of the `u` array: evaluation of the spline at `u`
# gives back the original points (up to a list/transpose)

xy = interpolate.splev(u, tck)
xy = np.asarray(xy)
np.allclose(xy.T, points)
```

Next, let's replicate it without `splprep`. First, build the `u` array: the curve is represented parametrically, and `u` is essentially an approximation for the arc length. Other parametrizations are possible, but here let's stick to what `splprep` does. Translating the pseudocode from the doc page, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html

```
vv = np.sum((points[1:, :] - points[:-1, :])**2, axis=1)
vv = np.sqrt(vv).cumsum()
vv/= vv[-1]
vv = np.r_[0, vv]

# check: 
np.allclose(u, vv)
```

Now, interpolate along the parametric curve: `points` vs `vv`:

```
spl = interpolate.make_interp_spline(vv, points)

# check spl.t vs knots from splPrep
spl.t - tck[0]
```

The result, `spl`, is a `BSpline` object which you can evaluate, differentiate etc in a usual way:

```
np.allclose(points, spl(vv))

# differentiate
spl_derivative = spl.derivative(vv)
```