# How to select control points for B-spline smoothing from a set of points?

Tags: matlab, smoothing, bspline

I have an initial path that resulted from RRT-connect algorithm in the form (xi,yi) and i want to smooth it using B-spline algorithm. The question is "Shall i consider all the returned (xi,yi) values as control points or shall i choose some? and if the second what are the criteria to choose some waypoints as control points and not the others?

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in approximating the polygonal line `(xi, yi)` with a smooth B-spline.
Instead of filtering the input points, I suggest you use a least-square B-spline fitting on all the input points. The result is a smooth spline, and you can control the fitting parameters to get a smoother or tighter curve approximation, as I show below.

The following python code produces a noisy polygonal line `(xi, yi)`, which I will use as an example for demonstration.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_sample_pts = 20
noise = 0.03
np.random.seed(0)

t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, num_sample_pts)
xi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, num_sample_pts) + noise * np.random.randn(num_sample_pts)
yi = np.sin(t) + noise * np.random.randn(num_sample_pts)

plt.figure()
plt.axis("equal")
plt.plot(xi, yi, 'r-*')
```

[image]

One fitting option is to **interpolate** your data points. This results in a spline curve that passes through all the input points. This usually results in a more "wavy" spline (depending on your input). Note that for B-spline fitting a parameterization `ui` is needed for each input point (see also my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68529576/9702190) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70926196/9702190) for further explanation).
A common parameterization in spline fitting is [the chord-length parameterization](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-chord-length.html). This parameterization is defined by the accumulated length of the distances between the ordered points (`u0=0, u1=|p1-p0|, u2 = u1+|p2-p1|`... etc.).

The code below uses `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` to interpolate the input points above and display the results over the above figure. The result is the green spline curve passing through the input points.

```
xy = np.vstack([xi, yi]).T
ui = np.cumsum(np.r_[[0], np.linalg.norm(np.diff(xy, axis=0), axis=1)])
sx = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(ui, xi)
sy = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(ui, yi)

# sampling the resulting spline and displaying the results
uu = np.linspace(ui[0], ui[-1], 100)
xx = sx(uu)
yy = sy(uu)
plt.plot(xx, yy, "g")
```

[image]

On the data above, this result may not be smooth enough. An alternative to interpolation is least-square approximation. The following code uses `scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline` to fit a smooth curve to the input.
Note that the least-square fit needs an additional parameter `knots` - adjusting this parameter can make a trade-off between smoothness and a tighter fit to the input points.

```
n = 2
knots = np.linspace(ui[0], ui[-1], n)
sx = interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline(ui, xi, knots[1:-1])
sy = interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline(ui, yi, knots[1:-1])
```

Plotting the result gives the following figure.

[image]

As noted above, the `knots` parameter can be adjusted, the following figure is a result of running the code above with `n=10`. It can be viewed as somewhere in between the interpolation and the previous least-square fit.

[image]

As can be seen from the examples, the smoothing can be played with depending on your data. Another alternative is to use `scipy.interpolate.splrep`, which has a smoothing parameter as part of its interface. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation) of these functions to find what suits your needs.

Comment: thank you for your explanation but I am not familiar with python language. if you could provide me some MATALB code for explanation it would be much more better.

Comment: I don't have access to a MATLAB interpreter but from what I see the MATLAB spap2 function (www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spap2.html) is similar to python's LSQUnivariateSpline I use. What's important is to set the ui parameters with accumulated length as I explain in the answer. sx = spap2(n,4,ui,xi); sy=spap2(n,4,ui,yi) should give you more or less the sx, sy result curve I show in the answer.